# How to create a ts object -ts() - with data provide in busines days and not starting at the beggining of the month?

Tags: r, import, formatting, time-series, temporal

I'm Christophe new in this forum and data science.

Sorry for my English and may be my question but I can't find an answer.

I try to modelinze a kaggle data ( (https://www.kaggle.com/brunotly/foreign-exchange-rates-per-dollar-20002019)) but I don't know how to create a ts() object starting not at the beggining of the month (2000/01/03) (%y%m%d) with a frequency ????

i have tried this command :

```
data<-ts(mydata, frequency=365, start=c(2000, 01))
```

but how to set the start a ts the 3rd of the month and not the first and second. How to say to r that the data as provide in businness day (excluding 2 days a week, this no row for non business day).

Thanks you for you answer and I hope I'm clear.

thanks a lot
christophe

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, the reason I built it this way is because ts() is used for univariate time series and your data has multiple columns associate with the time. If you need multi-variate time series, you need to use mts() function.

```
dates <- as.Date(mydata$Time.Serie)

data <- ts(mydata$AUSTRALIA...AUSTRALIAN.DOLLAR.US., start = c(2000, as.numeric(format(dates[1], "%j"))), frequency = 365)

print(data, calendar = T)
```

Output:
         p1     p2     p3     p4     p5     p6     p7     p8     p9    p10
2000               1.5172 1.5239 1.5267 1.5291 1.5272 1.5242 1.5209 1.5202